# Prove $\left| \sin x - x \right| \leq \frac{1}{6} \left| x\right|^3$ using Cauchy Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm asked to prove that $\left| \sin x - x \right| \leq \frac{1}{6} \left| x\right|^3$ using the Cauchy Mean Value theorem.
What I'm having trouble with is finding the right functions $f$ and $g$ for the CMVT:
    $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}.$$

My first thoughts where $f(x)= \sin(x)$, and $g(x)$ should be some power of $x$. But so far, I haven't gotten that to work out:

$$\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{x^6 - 0^6} = \frac{\cos c}{6 x^5}$$
   $$\sin(x) = \frac{1}{6} \frac{\cos(c) \, x^6}{x^5}$$
   $$\sin(x) = \frac{1}{6} \cos(c) \, x$$

I'm happy with having $f(x)=\sin(x)$ since $\left| \cos(x) \right| \leq 1$, but what is giving me trouble is finding a function such that I can have $x^3$ moved to the right hand side, and getting $\sin(x)-x$ on the left. I mean, $\sin(x)=x$ iff $x=0$, but I feel like I can't just replace $\sin(0)$ with $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sin x-x$ and  $g(x)=x^3$. Then
$$
\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{g(x)-g(0)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}=\frac{\cos c-1}{3c^2}
=-\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2\sin^2 (c/2)}{c^2}=-\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{\sin(c/2)}{c/2}\right)^2.
$$
And since $\lvert\sin a\rvert\le\lvert a\rvert$, then
$$
\left|\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\right|\le\frac{1}{6}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

> $$
> |\sin x - x| \le  \frac 16 |x|^3.
> $$

Proof:

$$
\sin x = \int_0^x \cos u du = [-(x-u)\cos u]_0^x
+\int_0^x (x-u)(-\sin u) du
\\
= x -  \frac 12 [-(x-u)^2\sin  u]_0^x 
- \frac 12 \int_0^x (x-u)^2\cos u du
= x -\frac 12 \int_0^x (x-u)^2\cos u du
$$

Now:
$$
\left|\frac 12 \int_0^x (x-u)^2\cos u du\right|
\le \left|\frac 12 \int_0^x (x-u)^2du\right| = \frac 16 |x|^3.
$$
Hence,
$$|x-\sin x|\le \frac 16 |x|^3.$$